# Regex - Find 'continue;' in switch

Tags: php, phpstorm

I'm trying to create a Regex for finding `continue;` within a switch.

This is what i have so far:

```
switch.*\s.*\s.*continue;
```

For this case the above Regex works.

```php
<?php
while ($foo) {
    switch ($bar) {
      case "baz":
         continue;
   }
}
```

But if you put `continue;` on a different line it breaks.

I'm searching for this within PhpStorm, so the multiline flag is not working to my knowledge.

The reason why I want to find continue in switches is explained in the PHP Migration Guide: https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration73.incompatible.php#migration73.incompatible.core.continue-targeting-switch

Comment: Use the `s` flag to make `.` match newlines. The name of this flag is "dotall", not "multiline".

Comment: But this won't find `continue` within `switch`. It will find `continue` anywhere after `switch`, even if it's not contained in the block.

Comment: Just run the built-in linter `php -l <file>` on your files and you'll get a warning about continues that target switches.

Comment: @AlexHowansky It's not an error if the switch is inside a loop.

Comment: FYI, the multiline flag makes `^` and `$` match beginning and end of lines rather than strings. It's always enabled in PhpStorm, since there's little point in treating the entire buffer as a single string.

Comment: @Barmar It's not an error, it's a warning, and you still get it if it's inside a loop but targeting the switch. https://3v4l.org/bCvuv

Comment: The code inspection within PHPStorm can pick it up with `'continue' is targeting 'switch' statement` even in a while loop. So no need for the regex anymore. :)

Comment: `find . -name "*.php" | xargs -n 1 php -l | grep 'targeting switch'`

Comment: @AlexHowansky FYI your find/grep command also triggers other stuff e.g. `PHP Deprecated:  Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP;`

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use [Structural search](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/structural-search-and-replace.html) instead. This pattern would work for your case:
[image]

Comment: This will work for the example case. But not if you put continue on a different line or even in a different case.